# Python Shareplum getListItems query

Tags: python, shareplum

Looking for direction with Python & Shareplum.

I am trying to run the following query (very much from the shareplum document),

```
fields = ['ID', 'Title', 'RaceDate', 'RaceNumber']
    query = {'Where': ['And', 
                        ('Eq', 'Title', location),
                        ('Eq', 'RaceDate', current_date),
                        ('Eq', 'RaceNumber', raceNumber)]}
    sp_raceChecklist_query = sp_raceChecklist.GetListItems(fields=fields, query=query)
```

however i get the following error:
shareplum.errors.ShareplumRequestError: Shareplum HTTP Post Failed : 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error for url: https://tsite.com/sites/list//_vti_bin/lists.asmx

The thing is that if my query has only to arguments, it works.  So for example, this works:

```
fields = ['ID', 'Title', 'RaceDate', 'RaceNumber']
    query = {'Where': ['And', 
                        ('Eq', 'Title', location),
                        ('Eq', 'RaceNumber', raceNumber)]}
    sp_raceChecklist_query = sp_raceChecklist.GetListItems(fields=fields, query=query)
```

Is my *where* query incorrect when trying to qualify against three columns?  Or is it not supported?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out

```
query = {'Where': ['And', ('Eq', 'Title', location),
                        'And',  ('Eq', 'RaceDate', current_date),
                                ('Eq', 'RaceNumber', raceNumber)]}
```

Just didn't look hard enough :-(